# How to "use" another module in perl mason?

Tags: perl, mason

In a regular perl script you can write

`use Foo::Crypt::Employee qw(foo);`

at the top of your file to use the `foo` subroutine throughout the rest of your script.

**How can I do this in a perl mason file?**  Where would I put such a line of code?

Comment: a <%init> block looks the best place

Comment: Nope that doesn't work

Comment: which version of mason is this, 1 or 2?

Comment: @Nosrettap yes it does. "Doesn't work" isn't a useful problem report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [External Modules](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JSWARTZ/HTML-Mason-0.896/htdocs/Admin.html#external_modules) in the HTML::Mason documentation.